# Procedure to delete employee records from employee table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create a procedure that deletes employee records from the Employee table. Get the department name as an input parameter. Delete the  employee records who belongs to that department.

Display the count of employee records that were deleted.  If the respective department was not found, then raise "DeptNotFoundException" and print the message 'No Records found.'

Assume the Employee table has been already created and a few records have been inserted.

EMPLOYEE:

```
Column name  Data type      Constraints
EMP_ID       NUMBER(5)      PK
EMP_NAME     VARCHAR2(25)   NOT NULL
SALARY       NUMBER(10,2)    
DEPT         VARCHAR2(25)    

EMP_ID EMP_NAME SALARY  DEPT
------ -------- ------- -----
101    Tom      54000   MECH
102    William  43000   CSE
103    John     34560   MECH
104    Smith    56000   CSE
105    Steve    23450   IT
```

Functional Requirements:
PROCEDURE DELETE_EMPLOYEE( v_dept IN EMPLOYEE.dept%TYPE)

Sample Output:
2 Employee record(s) got deleted.

(Hint: Data is case sensitive. Use '/' to terminate the PLSQL block)

I have tried to solve this using my own logic, but it is showing error(out of 2 test only one is passed) can anyone point out the mistake?

```
set serveroutput on;

create or replace PROCEDURE DELETE_EMPLOYEE(v_dept IN EMPLOYEE.dept%TYPE)
is 
    temp number;
    DEPTNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION Exception;
begin
    select count(dept) into temp from EMPLOYEE where dept=v_dept;

    delete from EMPLOYEE where dept=v_dept;

    if temp>=1 then
        dbms_output.put_line(temp||' Employee record(s) got deleted.');
    else
        raise DEPTNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION;
    end if;
exception
    when DEPTNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION then
        dbms_output.put_line('No Records Found.');
end;
/
```

Comment: So one test case works and another test case shows an error.  What test case works?  What test case fails?  What error is generated?

Comment: You don't need to count the number of rows in the department. After the `delete` statement, `sql%rowcount` will hold the number of rows that were processed.

Comment: As a point of best practice, it's good to make a distinction between variables and parameters, so I would name the department parameter something like `p_deptno` (other conventions include `in_` or `i_` prefixes for 'in' parameters, or prefix with the procedure name itself, although that can be a bit verbose.)

Comment: Your procedure works, though. What test is failing?

Comment: And following on from @WilliamRobertson, your local variables are better named with 'v_' prefix.  But in this case, as already pointed out, you don't need the 'temp' variable at all, regardless of what you name it.  And your "if temp>=1 " logic would be simpler as "if temp > 0".   Overall, you need to spend some time (and possible reading) thinking about standard naming conventions.  A good naming standard will create names that are un-ambiguous and self-documenting as to what they are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` and generally tidy up a bit but it doesn't look "wrong".

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY
  , emp_name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
  , salary NUMBER(10,2)    
  , dept VARCHAR2(25)
);

INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, emp_name, salary, dept) VALUES (101, 'Tom', 54000, 'MECH');
INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, emp_name, salary, dept) VALUES (102, 'William', 43000, 'CSE');
INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, emp_name, salary, dept) VALUES (103, 'John', 34560, 'MECH');
INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, emp_name, salary, dept) VALUES (104, 'Smith', 56000, 'CSE');
INSERT INTO employee (emp_id, emp_name, salary, dept) VALUES (105, 'Steve', 23450, 'IT');

DECLARE
    dept_not_found EXCEPTION;
    PROCEDURE delete_employee (p_dept IN employee.dept%TYPE) IS
    BEGIN
        DELETE employee
        WHERE dept = p_dept;
        IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
            RAISE dept_not_found;
        END IF;
        dbms_output.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT||' Employee record(s) got deleted.');
    END delete_employee;
BEGIN
    delete_employee('CSE');
    delete_employee('ZZZ');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN dept_not_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('No Records Found.');
END;
/
```

```text
2 Employee record(s) got deleted.
No Records Found.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Only an advice: Stop using `raise` when you want to output something. `raise` have always much more workload than:

```
if (sql%rowcount = 0) then
  DBMS_Output.Put_Line('No Record Found');
  return;
end if;
```